# Query IEnumerable list and from two object

Tags: c#, linq

How can I return a list of User/Person with certain types of group admin

Model

```
Person
    public class Person : Base
    {
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Name> PreferredName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Prefix> PrefixID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Gender> GenderID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ethnicity> EthnicityID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Email> EmailID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Roles> RoleID { get; set; }
}

Roles
public class Roles: Base
{
    {
     public string desc {get;set;}
    }
 }
```

This is my method that I am creating.

```
Method
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersonWithGroup(IEnumerable<Roles> r)
{
   return context.Person.Where(x => r.Contains(x.RoleID));
}
```

Comment: This looks like an `IQueryable`, not an `IEnumerable`.  You appear to be querying a database, not an in memory collection.

Comment: Does it have to be an exact match of all the roles or does it suffice for the person to belong to one or more of the roles you pass?

Comment: @Servy An `IQueryable` is an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @KennethK and a motorbike is a velocipede and you can push yourself along by your feet on one, but treating a motorbike like a velocipede is rarely the most efficient approach.

Comment: @Kenneth yes, but [`Enumerable.Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, Boolean>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) is a different function than  [`Queryable.Where<T>(this IQueryable<T>, Expression<Func<T, Boolean>>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx) with very different behaviors when you call them both on the same `IQuerable<T>` object.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing each of Roles object with a RoleID... You need to compare ID with ID. I would suggest something like this:

```
return context.Person.Where(x => r.Select(y => y.RoleID).Contains(x.RoleID));
```